# jquery event bubbling and mobile :active hacks

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm fixing the `:active` states of buttons on my mobile page like so:

```
$('body').on('touchstart', 'a', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
}).on('touchend touchcancel click', 'a', function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

This delegation/bubbling approach works great, because I'm doing lots of dynamic page manipulation and I don't want to have to constantly re-apply this hack.

However, now I have some additional code like this:

```
$('a#MyAnchor').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do something
    return false;
});
```

This of course prevents the first block from working :( Is there an elegant solution to this?

I know I can re-apply the hack to `#MyAnchor`, but that's ugly.

Is there a way to prevent clicking the `<a>` from causing a navigation, but allowing the click event to still propagate up the DOM?

Bonus: Can I also prevent other explicit `click` handlers attached to `#MyAnchor` from firing, but still allow the propagation up the DOM?

Comment: In general I think you do this sort of thing with classes. Add, say, a 'disabled' class to `<a id="MyAnchor">` and then read the class in your delegated handler.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably sorted this now, but it's annoying seeing unanswered questions when looking for a solution, so I'll add an answer anyway.
But would handling the body events through a single event function not work out, with maybe custom handlers in an array that it checks after? So like:

```
$('body').on('touchstart touchend touchcancel click', 'a', HandleInteraction);
```

and then:

```
var actions = [];

var HandleInteraction = function(event){
   // check event type
   // do action based on event type
   // check other actions handlers for action
   // check if event target is in actions
   // .call() / .apply() .handler from actions matching action
};
var HandleMyAnchor = function(event){
    // do something
    return false;
};
actions.push({ target: '#MyAnchor', handler: HandleMyAnchor });
```

perhaps not the *best* way, but it should work. You could even just expand `HandleInteraction` each time there was something more specific and just check the `event.target`.
But at least this way there are a lot less event handlers flying around through code.